# Tests using h2 and spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, testing, h2

I am developing an application using the Postgresql database, and using schema.
In Entity, I use annotation @table (schema = 'schema name').
When I run the tests on h2, I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "schema name" not found; SQL statement:
```

I tried to create the file
schema.sql, containing:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema name AUTHORIZATION sa;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shcema name2 AUTHORIZATION sa;
...
```

but without success.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define schema with spring.datasource.url property:

- spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT
  EXISTS schema name

Comment: i change to this

src->resources->schema.sql, And in application.properties  spring.datasource.schema=schema.sql.

Unsuccessfully.
If i do spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema name, works, but i have too many schemas...

Comment: That case you have multiple schema definitions, if you want to use schema from your sql file then remove ';INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS schema name' from 'spring.datasource.url' property